# Hilbert class fields and transfer

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/k$ be an extension of number fields and $H_k$, $H_K$ their respective Hilbert class fields. Is there a transfer map from $\text{Gal}(H_k/k)$ to $\text{Gal}(H_K/K)$?

Comment: There is of course the natural map of class groups \Cl(k)\to \Cl(K)... Are you asking whether the Verlagerung descends to a map between the two Galois groups?

Comment: Yes. How can the transfer induce such a map? I know the transfer from G to H/H', when H is a subgroup of finite index of G and H' is the derived subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I am terribly sorry, the question of course asked for a **transfer** map. I can leave my answer here if no one objects, but it is irrelevant for the question.

As it was already pointed out, there is a transfer map between the Galois groups induced by the class field theory isomorphisms. Another construction that I can think of comes from the isomorphism $K_0(R) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \operatorname{Pic}(R)$ for every Dedekind domain $R$, and then one can apply the existance of transfers in algebraic $K$-theory.

Sorry again for the wrong answer.

---

I think that one can argue that $H_{k} \subseteq H_K$ and conclude that there is a restriction map between the Galois groups.

One way to do this is look at the diagram

[image]

and observe that $H_k \cdot K$ is unramified over $K$, because for every prime $\mathfrak{Q}$ of $H_k \cdot K$ we have that
$$
e(\mathfrak{Q} \mid \mathfrak{P}) = e(\mathfrak{Q} \mid \mathfrak{p})/e(\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}) = e(\mathfrak{P'} \mid \mathfrak{p}) \cdot e(\mathfrak{Q} \mid \mathfrak{P}')/e(\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}) = e(\mathfrak{Q} \mid \mathfrak{P}')/e(\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}) = 1
$$ 
where $\mathfrak{P} := \mathfrak{Q} \cap K$, $\mathfrak{P}' := \mathfrak{Q} \cap H_k$ and $\mathfrak{p} := \mathfrak{Q} \cap (H_k \cap K)$. Observe that $e(\mathfrak{P'} \mid \mathfrak{p}) = 1$ because $H_k \cap K \subseteq H_k$ is unramified and $e(\mathfrak{Q} \mid \mathfrak{P}') = e(\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p})$ as it follows from the following local argument.

Consider a square of valued fields

[image]

where $M = L \cdot K$ and $F = L \cap K$. Then it induces a diamond of groups

[image]

and thus $e(\phi_M \mid \phi_L) := [\phi_M(M^{\times}) \colon \phi_L(L^{\times})] = [\phi_K(K^{\times}) \colon \phi_F(F^{\times})] = e(\phi_K \mid \phi_F)$ as it follows from the second isomorphism theorem in group theory (see [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-703-modern-algebra-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_703S13_pra_l_10.pdf), Theorem 10.3). Here of course, $\phi$ denotes the valuation associated to the given field.

Hence we can conclude that $H_K \supseteq H_k \cdot K$ by the characterizing property of the Hilbert class field, which is the biggest abelian extension of a field that is unramified everywhere. Hence $H_K \supseteq H_k$ and thus there is a restriction map $\operatorname{Gal}(H_K/K) \to \operatorname{Gal}(H_k/k)$.

On a side note, observe that this map could be trivial even if the two groups are not. An interesting example is when $H_k = K$ and $H_{H_k} \neq H_k$, which can happen even when $k$ is a quadratic field. In fact, it is a theorem of Golod and Shafarevic that if $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq k$ is an imaginary quadratic field ramified at more than six primes then it has an infinite class field tower (see [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/zhou/zhou.pdf) Harvard undergraduate thesis by Kathleen Zhou or [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07062) recent preprint by Farshid Hajir, Christian Maire and Ravi Ramakrishna).

P.S. Of course all along, $e(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ denotes the ramification index. For its definition in the context of valued fields see Section 3.3 of [these notes](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/vg.pdf) by Peter Stevenhagen.